# How to find the path of a tempfile that's uploaded in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to grab the audio file that's uploaded and get the length of it using taglib-ruby. Everything saves fine, but the track.duration is always nil. What am I doing wrong here?

```
class TracksController < ApplicationController
  require 'taglib'
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @track.update(track_params)
        file = params[:audio]
        TagLib::FileRef.open(file) do |fileref|
            unless fileref.null?
                tag = fileref.tag
                # properties = fileref.audio_properties
                properties = fileref.audio_properties
                properties.length
                @track.update_column(:duration => properties.length)
            end
        end
        format.html { redirect_to @track, notice: 'Track was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
      end
    end
  end
```

Instead of file I have also tried @tempfile, @tempfile.path, I've even put in the Amazon S3 url to try to open the mp3 file that way. Here is what I'm getting in the rails console when I upload a track. I'm only posting the part that is contained in :audio.

```
"audio"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f3a06463358 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20190827-15418-lq5o52.mp3>, @original_filename="Gary the Goat.mp3", @content_type="audio/mp3", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"track[audio]\"; filename=\"Gary the Goat.mp3\"\r\nContent-Type: audio/mp3\r\n">,
```

I thought that

```
@tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20190827-15418-lq5o52.mp3>
```

would be the thing I need to open with Taglib so it can get the duration but simply using @tempfile doesn't work.

Comment: What if the mp3 file is lengthless xD

Comment: I'm asking for when it is not.

Comment: Check this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files try `params[:audio].path` or save the file to a specific location using that snippet to be sure the path is not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you use `properties.length` contains the length? Check the properties using `puts properties.length`

If it does, probably you have an issue on `update_column`.

```
properties = fileref.audio_properties
puts properties.length # 345
@track.duration = properties.length
@track.save # or .save!
```